# I want a vibration when user clicks on the button , I implemented the HapticFeedback but it not working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, haptic-feedback

Below is my code for the Button and I want to vibrate it when user press the button.
I also added the permission in AndroidManifest and tried all the methods of HapticFeedback but none of them works

```
     Material(
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          HapticFeedback.vibrate();
                                          CollectionReference ref= FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                              .collection("users")
                                              .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                              .collection('Favourites');
                                          var data={
                                            'Quote': Show_It[index].quote,
                                            'author': Show_It[index].author,
                                          };
                                          ref.add(data).then((value) => {
                                            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Added to Favourites")
                                          });
                                        },
                                        splashRadius: 20,
                                        splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          Icons.favorite,
                                          color: Colors.red,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
```

And Below is my AndroidManifest file in which i applied the permission for vibration but still nothing happens

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.make_your_day">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   <application
        android:label="make_your_day"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```